# Confused about LND derivation of node's payee pubkeys

Tags: seed

Okay. A short summary of the problem: I'm trying to derive the root key from LND from the aezeed, but I can't get it right.

Assume the following seed (aezeed):

```
ability quality bulb clap quality piano focus ivory trust essence improve book antique analyst double equip reason venue jazz zoo host potato harvest divorce
```

For which the following root keys result:

```
tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPct7CvypLfrMHfanE3cmTwZuy8QTGNgzFZKSqFeXXinsuKvkyMe6DbqdGMu8Xp1fon8E3mgW62RiorqMv6qLV2dqPFX3pETp
xprv9s21ZrQH143K24sgGQxqWCjJMTN1p6jTc1zrFz2otiVmmihkGHBnD3WTQkbKMGhuEQ6VMoWmef61KGgJeUA9DNTDLC9cSUcS7Y5xos3tfBr
```

To check if these are correct, we derive the node's payee key (identity pubkey), which is `m/1017'/0'/6'/0/0`

results in `03bb9f9f7734ca9da4ec06543d32456384f878303305a72979e7316825e00749ad`

the problem is; the above seed results in `039e625ffe5325224e6273fc5e0afe59f7ec82cb90add45e76f34cfff9efdcac60`
(as per LND's getinfo)

Anyone who can spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong cointype. I'm assuming mainnet = 0, and testnet = 1,  although I can't find any documentation on this.

```
m/1017'/1'/6'/0
```

gives the correct identity key.